# Find index of first max in list compraring to a value in python

Tags: python

I have a sorted list

```
my_list = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384]
```

I have a value lets say 445. I want to find the index of first max in list. For above case, it should return  index value 9 (512).

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. Any requirement regarding complexity?

Comment: use `for i, v in enumerate(my_list):` to populate both index and value.

Comment: It is prefered to avoid loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use binary search to find the required index, because the input list is sorted. This algorithm is already implemented in the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module:

```
import bisect

my_list = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384]
print(bisect.bisect_right(my_list, 445))
print(bisect.bisect_right(my_list, 512))
```

Prints:

```
9
10
```